# Remove just one char in while

Tags: php

How can I trim just one character inside a `while`? See this example:

> **What I want to get:**
>
> ```
> [{"lat":"mylat","lng":"mylong","dragable":"false"},
>  {"lat":"mylat","lng":"mylong","dragable":"false"}]`
> ```
>
> **What I'm getting:**
>
> ```
> [{"lat":"mylat","lng":"mylong","dragable":"false"},
>  {"lat":"mylat","lng":"","dragable":"false"},]
> ```

I want to remove just the comma that is between `}` and `]`, but I don't know how.

---

The code:

```
print "[";
if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $locs_json = sprintf(json_encode(array("lat"=>"%s", "lng"=>"%s", "dragable"=>"false")),$row[0],$row[1]);
    $locs = $locs_json.",";
    print $locs;
  }
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}
print "]";
```

---

I've tried adding a `rtrim($locs, ",");` after the print, but it removes all the commas, and I need all of them except the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it storing the string in a variable.

When you finish adding values, you do the `rtrim`, and then add the square bracket and print it.

```
$myString = "[";
if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $locs_json = sprintf(json_encode(array("lat"=>"%s", "lng"=>"%s", "dragable"=>"false")),$row[0],$row[1]);
    $locs = $locs_json.",";
    $myString .= $locs;
  }
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  $myString = rtrim($myString, ",");
}
$myString .= "]";

print $myString;
```

Comment: With this, I get all the commas including the one that I want to remove @nanocv

Comment: @DiegoBarreiro my fault! fixed it! you have to reassign the result of rtrim to the variable

Comment: Thank you @nanocv, now it works perfectly! Thanks a lot

Comment: @DiegoBarreiro happy about that! please, consider to upvote and validate the answer

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are try to encode into JSON, part manually, and part using `json_encode()`. You can get `json_encode()` to do all the work:

```
$rows = [];
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $rows[] = [
            'lat' => $row[0],
            'lng' => $row[1],
            'dragable' => 'false',
        ];
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print "[";
if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
  $i = 1;
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $locs_json = sprintf(json_encode(array("lat"=>"%s", "lng"=>"%s", "dragable"=>"false")),$row[0],$row[1]);

    echo ($i >1 && !empty($locs_json)) ? ',' : '';
    print $locs_json;
    $i++;
  }
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}
print "]";
```

Simple solution: Add a counter and print comma based on value of counter

Comment: With this, I don't get any comma, but I want to get all commas except the last one

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: Yes @Ima, but the output is not what I'm looking for. I used nanocv answer and it works for me

Comment: Ok found an error! corrected. Variable name was wrong. Anyway good that you got working code